# Common pitfalls/causes of bad vertex data?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, 3d, mesh

So, I've been working on this .OBJ/.MTL mesh parser for the past week and a half. Within this time I've been tracking down/fixing a lot of bugs, cleaning up code, documenting it, etc etc.

The problem is that, with every bug I fix, there still is this issue which crops up, and since a picture is worth a thousand words...

**Using GL_LINE_LOOP**

(NOTE: the pyramid on the right tipping outward from the sphere is the problem here)

[image: sphere line loop]

**Using GL_TRIANGLES**

[image: sphere triangles]

What's even more interesting is that this "bad" vertex data appears to move with the camera when floating around the scene...except that it scales and sticks outside of the mesh.

The odd thing here is that while I'm sure the issue has something to do with memory, I've been checking for issues which contradict whether or not the parsing algorithm works properly. After some unit tests, it appears to be working fine.

So, I thought it may be a Linux nVidia driver issue. I updated the driver to the next version, restarted, and still no dice.

After some heavy thinking, I've been trying to find errors in the following code.

```
            //! every 3 vertices should represent a triangle, therefore we'll want to
            //! use the indices to grab their corresponding vertices. Since the cross product
            //! of two sides of every triangle (where one side = Vn - Vm, 'n' and 'm' being on the range of 1..3),
            //! we first grab the three vertices, and then compute the normal using the their differences.

            const uInt32 length = mesh->vertices.size();

            //! declare a pointer to the vector so we can perform simple
            //! memory copies to get the indices for each triangle within the
            //! iteration.

            GLuint* const pIndexBuf = &mesh->indices[ 0 ];

            for ( uInt32 i = 0; i < length; i += 3 )
            {
                GLuint thisTriIndices[ 3 ];

                memcpy( thisTriIndices, pIndexBuf + i, sizeof( GLuint ) * 3 );

                vec3 vertexOne   = vec3( mesh->vertices[ thisTriIndices[ 0 ] ] );
                vec3 vertexTwo   = vec3( mesh->vertices[ thisTriIndices[ 1 ] ] );
                vec3 vertexThree = vec3( mesh->vertices[ thisTriIndices[ 2 ] ] );

                vec3 sideOne        = vertexTwo - vertexOne;
                vec3 sideTwo        = vertexThree - vertexOne;

                vec3 surfaceNormal  = glm::cross( sideOne, sideTwo );

                mesh->normals.push_back( surfaceNormal );
            }
```

The current one shown in the picture doesn't even have normal data, so the idea is to compute surface normals for it, hence the above code. While I've made some checks to see if the index data was being loaded properly within the loop, I haven't been able to find anything yet.

I think the way I'm laying out my memory might have problems too, but I can't quite put my finger on what the problem would be. In case I've missed something, I'll throw in my glVertexAttribPointer calls:

```
//! Gen some buf handles

    glGenBuffers( NUM_BUFFERS_PER_MESH, mesh->buffers );

    //! Load the respective buffer data for the mesh

    __LoadVec4Buffer( mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_VERTEX ], mesh->vertices );      //! positons
    __LoadVec4Buffer( mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_COLOR ], mesh->colors );         //! material colors
    __LoadVec3Buffer( mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_NORMAL ], mesh->normals );       //! normals
    __LoadIndexBuffer( mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_INDEX ], mesh->indices );       //! indices

    //! assign the vertex array a value

    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &mesh->vertexArray );

    //! Specify the memory layout for each attribute

    glBindVertexArray( mesh->vertexArray );

    //! Position and color are both stored in BUFFER_VERTEX.

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_VERTEX ] );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray( meshProgram->attributes[ "position" ] );
    glVertexAttribPointer( meshProgram->attributes[ "position" ],               //! index
                           4,                                                   //! num vals
                           GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,                                  //! value type, normalized?
                           sizeof( vec4 ),                                      //! number of bytes until next value in the buffer
                           ( void* ) 0 );                                       //! offset of the memory in the buffer

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_COLOR ] );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray( meshProgram->attributes[ "color" ] );
    glVertexAttribPointer( meshProgram->attributes[ "color" ],
                           4,
                           GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                           sizeof( vec4 ),
                           ( void* ) 0 );

    //! Now we specify the layout for the normals

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_NORMAL ] );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray( meshProgram->attributes[ "normal" ] );
    glVertexAttribPointer( meshProgram->attributes[ "normal" ],
                           3,
                           GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                           sizeof( vec3 ),
                           ( void* )0 );

    //! Include the index buffer within the vertex array

    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->buffers[ BUFFER_INDEX ] );

    glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

Any kind of point in the right direction at the very least would be appreciated: I have no idea what the common causes are for these issues.

**Edit: posted draw code on request**

```
glBindVertexArray( mMeshes[ i ]->vertexArray );

UBO::LoadMatrix4( UBO::MATRIX_MODELVIEW, modelView.top() );
UBO::LoadMatrix4( UBO::MATRIX_PROJECTION, camera.projection() );

glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, mMeshes[ i ]->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ( void* )0 );

glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

Comment: Where do you actually draw it?

Comment: Posted. It's within a draw loop, but I have the other mesh initialization code commented out, so there is effectively only one draw call at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to use the size of vertices for computing the normals, and not the number of triangles in the mesh?  If _length_ isn't a multiple of three, you're likely reading bad memory, and then who knows what values you're using.  (and for bonus points, replace the `memcpy` with a const pointer).

Comment: @radical7 You mean like this? http://pastebin.com/cX1DjCHW

Comment: @blissfreak Nicely done on the pointer implementation; full marks.  However, the normal computation still isn't there.  Using the number of vertices as a measure of the number of triangles for _indexed_ rendering isn't right - you need to use the number of indices (combined with the primitive type; you're okay this time since the number of verts/primitive for `GL_TRIANGLES` is 3).  I'm pretty sure you should have `numTris = mesh->indices.size()`, and you should also round _numTris_ down to the closest multiple of three.  Rounding up (as you do) could also reference unallocated memory.

Comment: @radical7 I see what you mean. Unfortunately I'm still having issues, despite doing what you suggest - what you say makes perfect sense though. Regardless, I appreciate the help; if you have any other suggestions I'm totally open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the final culprit, in conjunction with @radical7's suggestions, these fixed the issue for the most part.

```
            // round mesh->indices.size() down if it's not already divisible by 3.
            // the rounded value is stored in numTris

        std::vector< vec4 > newVertices;

        uInt32 indicesLen = Math_FloorForMultiple( mesh->indices.size(), 3 );

            // declare a pointer to the vector so we can perform simple
            // memory copies to get the indices for each triangle within the
            // iteration.

        newVertices.reserve( indicesLen );

        const GLuint* const pIndexBuf = &mesh->indices[ 0 ];

        for ( uInt32 i = 0; i < indicesLen; i += 3 )
        {
            const GLuint* const thisTriIndices = pIndexBuf + i;

            vec4 vertexOne   = mesh->vertices[ thisTriIndices[ 0 ] - 1 ];
            vec4 vertexTwo   = mesh->vertices[ thisTriIndices[ 1 ] - 1 ];
            vec4 vertexThree = mesh->vertices[ thisTriIndices[ 2 ] - 1 ];

            vec4 sideOne     = vertexTwo - vertexOne;
            vec4 sideTwo     = vertexThree - vertexOne;

            vec3 surfaceNormal = glm::cross( vec3( sideOne ), vec3( sideTwo ) );

            mesh->normals.push_back( surfaceNormal );
            mesh->normals.push_back( surfaceNormal + vec3( sideOne ) );
            mesh->normals.push_back( surfaceNormal + vec3( sideTwo ) );

            newVertices.push_back( vertexOne );
            newVertices.push_back( vertexTwo );
            newVertices.push_back( vertexThree );
        }


        mesh->vertices.clear();
        mesh->vertices = newVertices;
```

Note that when the vertices are grabbed in the loop, via the call to `mesh->vertices[ thisTriIndices[ x ] - 1 ]`, the `- 1` is extremely important: OBJ mesh files store their face indices starting from 1...N indices, as opposed to 0....N-1 indices.

The indices themselves also shouldn't be used to draw the mesh, but rather as a means to obtain a new buffer of vertices from an already temporary buffer of vertices: you use the indices to access the elements within the temporary vertices, and then for each vertex obtained from the temp buffer, you *add* that vertex to a new buffer. This way, you'll get the number of vertices specified in the correct draw order. Thus, you want to draw them using vertex arrays only.

Comment: Glad you found the problem.